# How to work out side length of a square with 3 unit circles

Tags: geometry

How do you work out the side length of a square which contains 3 packed circles of radius 1:

[image]

["Circles packed in square 3" by Toby Hudson - Own work. Licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 via Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Circles_packed_in_square_3.svg#mediaviewer/File:Circles_packed_in_square_3.svg)

[Circle packing in a square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square)

What is the method to get this answer?

Comment: An interpretation of your question with a relatively easy answer is how to find the side length of the square, assuming the symmetry and tangency of the unit circles apparent in the picture.  An interpretation that poses a more difficult problem is how to prove that this is the minimum side length of a square holding three packed unit circles.

Comment: I've a question, very common on M SE, What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use this diagram and analytic geometry:

[image: Square of 3 packed circles]

Put unit circles centered at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$, then another unit circle touching them, above them and centered at $(0, \sqrt{3})$. These will be the three packed circles inside the desired square.

Find the point $E$ on the upper circle that makes a $45°$ (or $135°$) angle with the $y$-axis. Draw the line through $E$ tangent to the circle. Similarly, find point $B'_1$ on the right circle that makes a $45°$ (or $135°$) angle with the $x$-axis and draw the tangent line through it. The intersection point $G$ of these two lines is a corner of the square, and points $F$ and $H$, intersections of the tangent lines with the $y$-axis, are other corners.

The desired square length is the length of segment $FG$ or segment $GH$. You should be able to find all these points and lengths by basic analytic geometry.